# How can I breed villagers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I still didn't succeded in breeding villagers. I tried with information from the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/villagers) and still I didn't succeded. I tried to breed villagers by trade,but they did not do that. I also tried the breeding with food,but with no succes. I built them additional houses,with no succes. Do the villagers need all the foods or just one. Have I got anything wrong?

Comment: *Each Villager* needs to have enough food to make them willing to breed, and even then it's a slow process.